# Format Number in Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, formatting, google-forms

How can I make a form submission like 1234 return 1,234?

Right now

var price = 1234

PLEASE help turn this into 1,234

Answer (score 3):

Just use `toLocaleString` as in

```
var n = 1234;
alert(n.toLocaleString());
```

The [language spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.4.3) says

> Produces a String value that represents this Number value formatted according to the conventions of the host environment’s current locale.

so it should format the number with the user's preferred [digit grouping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping), and the right [decimal separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator).

Answer (score 1):

Try a function like this.

```
function comma(num){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(num.toString())){
        num = num.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }
    return num;
}
```

Then, call it with

```
comma(1234); // "1,234"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about how to control the format of responses in Google Forms: Google Forms does not give you any way to manage the format of responses that are accepted.

You can control the format of values in the spreadsheet that accepts the responses, and you need no script for that. To do so, go to the response spreadsheet, select the cells in the column that contains the numbers you are interested in, and select your desired format from the menu.

This will affect how the numbers appear in the spreadsheet only - any script handling responses will be dealing with a javascript Number object, which has no format. See the answers from Mike or Overcode for options to generate a formatted string from a Number.

Comment: Note: this does not work with "New Forms" (2014), as now a new row is inserted with each form submission, with default (auto) formatting.

Answer (score -1):

var price = 1234;

price.setNumberFormat("#,000.00");

Comment: Be careful, the .setNumberFormat function is to be called upon a range, not an integer. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String)

Comment: Yes because I already did this in our actual script. 

sheet.getRange(lastRow + 6, 4).setValue(totB2B).setNumberFormat("#,###.00").setFontWeight("bold");